# How to stop RStudio from rendering nb.html on save of an R Markdown document

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudio renders `mynotebook.nb.html` file every time R Markdown document `mynotebook.Rmd` is saved. This process does not involve running code in chunks, so it is much faster than knitting a notebook into `mynotebook.html`. However, for large `.Rmd` documents, saving `nb.html` files can take a long time, and, unfortunately, it is required to wait for it to finish before one can start using the notebook again and run code in chunks.

Is there a way to configure RStudio to not to create `nb.html` files on save of an R Markdown document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found out you can delete relevant output entry from the top section of your file. In my case it looks like:

```
---
title: "Document"
output:
html_notebook: default
---
```

Which causes creation of `.nb.html` on every save. If you remove the `output` tag, file is no longer created automatically. You can still knit to any output file from the [Knit menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKuJL.png) on the top (or press `Ctrl+Shift+K` for default. This will run all the chunks again, which may take a while.

You may want to consult [this guide book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html) for more information on how YAML tags work. I'm just beginning with them!

Comment: Thanks @Dedalus, spot on. I did have `html_document` setting in the top section, which I must have unthinkingly copied from somewhere and forgot about it. Deleting it stops the behaviour that I had described, and it is still possible to knit the HTML document with custom setting, because they are controlled in a different YAML tag, `html_document`. The guide book is a great resource!

Answer (score 1):

Another reason (and solution) might be, that you clicked incidentally on the "Knit on Save" button located just under the Save-to-Disk-Symbol in RStudio. This was in my case the problem. Usually you should be able to save a rmd-file without triggering the knitting process.
So - given this scenario - just uncheck the "Knit on Save" button.